# Installing segment to Concept N

Tags: sony-future-lab-n

I have pushed my segment to the device, I can see it and launch it, but it never activates. It just keeps saying ‘retrieving’ over and over again. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that can be resolved by restarting the Concept N device. Try that and let me know if you are still having trouble.